# Tf-Idf vectorizer analyze vectors from lines instead of words

Tags: python, scikit-learn, vectorization, tf-idf, text-analysis

I'm trying to analyze a text which is given by lines, and I wish to vectorize the lines using sckit-learn package's TF-IDF-vectorization in python.
The problem is that the vectorization can be done either by words or n-grams but I want them to be done for lines, and I already ruled out a work around that just vectorize each line as a single word (since in that way the words and their meaning wont be considered).

Looking through the documentation I didnt find how to do that, so is there any such option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding what the TF-IDF vectorization is doing. For each word (or N-gram), it assigns a weight to the word which is a function of both the frequency of the term (TF) and of its inverse frequency of the other terms in the document (IDF). It makes sense to use it for words (e.g. knowing how often  the word "pizza" comes up) or for N-grams (e.g. "Cheese pizza" for a 2-gram)

Now, if you do it on lines, what will happen? Unless you happen to have a corpus in which lines are repeated exactly (e.g. "I need help in Python"), your TF-IDF transformation will be garbage, as each sentence will appear exactly once in the document. And if your sentences are indeed always similar to the punctuation mark, then for all intents and purposes they are not sentences in your corpus, but words. This is why there is no option to do TF-IDF with sentences: it makes zero practical or theoretical sense.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, and thats exactly what I want to do. I have lines that repeated almost exactly.

Comment: That's the point : if they are ALMOST exactly repeated, then they will be completely different in the eye of Scikit, in the same way that a TF-IDF transformation on words will treat "Word" and "Work" as completely different words. If what you want is analyze their similarity FROM the repetition of identical words, then you need to vectorize them on their word (or N-grams) content, and then compare the vector or one sentence to the vector of another. If you want to compare a full document to another, then you compare the mean cosine difference of sentences between documents.

Comment: I want to do something like n-grams analysis, the problem is that my lines are of different length.

Comment: That way sentences that differ by one words should be pretty similar by their vector weights

Comment: Then a simple word or bigram analysis is fine. Try it yourself: convert your full corpus of sentences in the TF-IDF vector space (using single words as the unit of analysis), and compare the cosine similarity of two sentences which only vary by one extremely frequent word (for instance a "The"), two sentences which vary by one extremely infrequent word ("platypus"), and two sentences which are completely different. You'll see the cosine similarities decrease from the first comparison to the last.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Can you please explain how i can find the similarities of two sentences by that method? after transforming to the vector space

Comment: I'll refer you to this tutorial (you can skip the math and jump straight to the "practice"  section) : http://blog.christianperone.com/2013/09/machine-learning-cosine-similarity-for-vector-space-models-part-iii/

Comment: If it is still unclear, I'll provide an example of code myself once I get to my computer, I'm on my phone right now.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out and do what you wanted to do?